# Как остановить анимацию, чтобы она не исчезала, когда закончилась?

Tags: css3

Как остановить анимацию, чтобы она не исчезала, когда закончилась?

```
@keyframes men{
from{
      background: linear-gradient(120deg, #CFA883 10%, white 20%, white 20%, #CFA883 30%);
      opacity:0;
    }
to {
    background-position:300px;
    opacity:1;
    }
}

div{
width:200px;
    height:100px;
    border:1px black solid;
}
div:hover{
    animation: men 2s;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Кмк у вас в параметре анимации `to` указаны только позиция и прозрачность. Соответственно сам градиент и пропадает в конце. Нужно его оставить (или что-то прописать вместо него - оконечный результат цвета) и еще дописать `animation-fill-mode: forwards;` в css.

[animation-fill-mode: forwards](https://webref.ru/css/animation-fill-mode) - к элементу по окончанию анимации применяется стиль последнего ключевого кадра

```css
@keyframes men {
  from {
    background: linear-gradient(120deg, #CFA883 10%, white 20%, white 20%, #CFA883 30%);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    background: linear-gradient(120deg, #CFA883 10%, white 20%, white 20%, #CFA883 30%);
    background-position: 200px;
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
div {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px black solid;
}
div:hover {
  animation: men 2s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```